# Can someone point me to some guides for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I am having trouble finding good guides for WPF.
I have experience in C# and .NET but  I don't know anything about WPF except for the regular marketing-ish description of the technology as a whole.
Can anyone point me to a good beginner's tutorial/guide on WPF.

Comment: You may follow two blogs on WPF. Good to understand the concept. 1) [http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/) 2) [http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.in](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.in/2012/03/introduction-to-windows-presentation.html)

Answer (score 6):

Scott Hanselmann has blogged extensively about his experience in learning WPF by creating his 'BabySmash' windows application. All the source code is on codeplex and he has many blog articles describing his progress.

[Initial BabySmash article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingBabySmashAWPFExperiment.aspx)

[Codeplex source](http://www.codeplex.com/babysmash/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx)

[BabySmash website](http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/)

Comment: Code is now here: https://github.com/shanselman/babysmash

Answer (score 4):

Ok, in terms of reading material, this is the pick of the books out there: [Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917).

For blogs, there are a lot of blogs and articles on [WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/), and there's an excellent blog all about data binding in WPF by [Beatriz Costa](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/). Also take a look at [LearnWPF.com](http://learnwpf.com/) and [Ask Dr. WPF](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/).

Answer (score 4):

Sacha Barber has a great series of articles on WPF for Beginners over at Codeproject that you can check out.

- [An Introduction to the WPF Layout System](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx)
- [An introduction into XAML / code and WPF resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF2.aspx)
- [An introduction into RoutedEvents / RoutedCommands](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF3.aspx)
- [An introduction into WPF Dependancy Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF4.aspx)
- [An introduction into WPF Styles And Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would buy a book - the Adam Nathan WPF book is good.

[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Presentation-Foundation-Unleashed-WPF/dp/0672328917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917)

Comment: It's a bit outdated though. I picked it up and some of the samples don't work because it was based off the beta.

Comment: I bought this book on other's recommendations but don't feel it is a good beginners book at all.  It dives way too deep in the beginning for me with no hands on examples to cement the knowledge he is trying to impart.  I'm a self-taught .Net programmer (been doing embedded programming for decades) but have been using Winforms for about a year and a half and feel WPF is the way to go for my next project.  I am sure that if I knew more it would be a good book since many others have recommended it but for me as a complete beginner it was too deep too fast and not enough hands on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few "How Do I" videos to get you started:

http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Programming WPF by Chris Sells and Ian Griffiths is an excellent way to learn WPF.  5 star rated on Amazon with 50+ reviews.  [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WPF-Chris-Sells/dp/0596510373](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Guided tour of WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/) by Josh Smith. I also really like Adam's Nathan book WPF Presentation Unleashed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some WPF getting started guides here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119.aspx